# Execve not working as expected

Tags: c, fork, exec, execve

I am writing a basic shell in c that will allow me to execute simple commands(I am not asked to check for optional arguments) like "ls" in a server (localhost). The program must be able to handle multiple clients.

I have done everything up to the part I have to execute the command with execve() (I MUST USE THIS FUNCION). I've found that execve() returns -1 on failure and that it doesn't return anything on success so I am making a fork() to execute the command in that process.

Now, to the problem. How do I know if execve() executed successfully? I can't seem to find the problem, my code always returns "OK" to the client.
"csapp.h" it's just a source file containing wrappers around some functions.

```
#include "csapp.h"

void echo(int connfd, pid_t pid);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int listenfd, connfd;
    unsigned int clientlen;
    struct sockaddr_in clientaddr;
    struct hostent *hp;
    char *haddrp, *port;
    pid_t pid;

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s <port>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(0);
    }
    port = argv[1];

    listenfd = Open_listenfd(port);
    while (1) {
        clientlen = sizeof(clientaddr);
        while(1){
            connfd = Accept(listenfd, (SA *)&clientaddr, &clientlen);
            if((pid=Fork())==-1){
                Close(connfd);
            }
            if(pid > 0){
                break;
            }
        }

        /* Determine the domain name and IP address of the client */
        hp = Gethostbyaddr((const char *)&clientaddr.sin_addr.s_addr,
                    sizeof(clientaddr.sin_addr.s_addr), AF_INET);
        haddrp = inet_ntoa(clientaddr.sin_addr);
        printf("server connected to %s (%s)\n", hp->h_name, haddrp);

        echo(connfd, pid);
        Close(connfd);
    }
    exit(0);
}

void trim(char *string){
    string[strlen(string)-1]=0;

}

char* concat(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    char *result = malloc(strlen(s1) + strlen(s2) + 1); // +1 for the null-terminator
    // in real code you would check for errors in malloc here
    strcpy(result, s1);
    strcat(result, s2);
    return result;
}

void echo(int connfd, pid_t pid)
{
    size_t n;
    char buf[MAXLINE];
    rio_t rio;

    char *args[2];

    args[1] = NULL;

    Rio_readinitb(&rio, connfd);
    while((n = Rio_readlineb(&rio, buf, MAXLINE)) != 0) {
        trim(buf);
        args[0] = concat("/bin/", buf);
        printf("server received %lu bytes\n", n);
        printf("Command: %s\n",buf);
        pid_t execPID;
        int status;
        if((execPID = fork()) > pid){
            execve(args[0],args,NULL);
        }else{

            wait(&status);
            if(WIFEXITED(status)){
                if (WEXITSTATUS(status) == 0){
                    printf("status: %d\n", status);
                    printf("WIFEXITED: %d\n", WIFEXITED(status));
                    printf("WEXITSTATUS: %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(status));
                        Rio_writen(connfd, "OK\n", 3); 
                }
                else
                        Rio_writen(connfd, "ERROR\n", 6);

            }
        }
        /*if(status == -1){
                Rio_writen(connfd, "ERROR\n", 6);

        }
            else{
                Rio_writen(connfd, "OK\n", 3);
                printf("%d\n", status);
            }*/


    }

}
```

Output for "m" and "ls" sent by the client:

```
server received 2 bytes
Command: m
status: 0
WIFEXITED: 1
WEXITSTATUS: 0
server received 3 bytes
Command: ls
status: 0
WIFEXITED: 1
WEXITSTATUS: 0
Makefile   client    csapp.c  csapp.o  server.c
README.md  client.c  csapp.h  server
```

I'd really appreciate some help, I've been stuck at this for the past 14 hours.

Comment: So you begin in C and you want to make a shell server... that a lot. Your question is not clear, too broad, and don't have a [mcve]. Read [ask]

Comment: `wait(&status);` you didn't look the error status of `wait()`, plus don't use `wait()` it's "obsolete", use `waitpid()` to be sure to wait the good child.

Comment: `if((execPID = fork()) > pid)` don't make any sense, you should verify that `fork()` is a success and then just compare it to `0` to now if it's a child, as you did in your first `fork()`

Comment: @Stargateur wait(&status) and waitpid(-1,&status,0) always returns -1, no matter if the command ran successfully or didn't at all

Comment: ["wait(): on success, returns the process ID of the terminated child; on error, -1 is returned.

waitpid(): on success, returns the process ID of the child whose state has changed; if WNOHANG was specified and one or more child(ren) specified by pid exist, but have not yet changed state, then 0 is returned. On error, -1 is returned."](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html), Are you **sure** ? Look the error so !

Comment: @Stargateur Output: server received 3 bytes
Command: ls
Check: -1
status: 0
WIFEXITED: 1
WEXITSTATUS: 0
Makefile   client    csapp.c  csapp.o  server.c
README.md  client.c  csapp.h  server
server received 7 bytes
Command: asdasd
execve failed: No such file or directory
Check: -1
status: 0
WIFEXITED: 1
WEXITSTATUS: 0

Comment: Look the error, mean look `errno`, use `perror("wait():");` for a print it.

Comment: @Stargateur I know wait returns the pid of the terminated child, then that means wait and waitpid cannot retrieve de pid of the child process, why?

Comment: @Stargateur Ok, I added perror("wait::") after the line wait(&status) and output is: "wait():: No child processes", so I guess fork is not working?

Comment: I think it's because it's not the parent who run `wait()` do a proper `fork()` as I said in my third comment.

Comment: @Stargateur Ok, I'm lost, I put this instead of previous if statement and still doesn't work: if((execPID = fork()) == -1){
   close(connfd);
  }
  if(execPID > 0){
   execve(args[0],args,NULL);
   perror( "execve failed" );
       exit( EXIT_FAILURE);

Comment: You doing it wrong, it's the child who must execute the command, so when `execPID` is `0`, not when `> 0`

Comment: @Stargateur DUDE I OWE YOU MY LIFE, I could've sworn that pid = 0 when it's the parent proces, THANKS! I want to mark this as the right answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @[Stargateur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7076153/stargateur) said in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51777853/execve-not-working-as-expected#comment90514222_51777853) below the question, I was doing wrong the comparison of execPID. Basically, pid is positive when it's the parent process and zero when it's the child process, so changing `if ((execPID = fork()) > pid)` to `if ((execPID = fork()) == 0)` actually solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I know if execve() executed successfully?

In the first place, as you've already observed, the server knows that the `execve()` call itself has failed if it returns at all.

In the second place, after the child process terminates, `wait()` or `waitpid()` can tell you what its exit status was.  You seem to have that worked out, too.

So when you go on to say,

> I can't seem to find the problem, my code always returns "OK" to the client.

, that leads me to believe that your actual question is more along the lines of "how do I get the command's *output*?"  Answer: via the child's standard output and (possibly) standard error streams.  How else?

By default, the child inherits its standard input, standard output, and standard error from its parent, but you can give it different ones by calling [`dup2()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup.2.html) in the child process before `execve()`.  You can do a variety of fairly sophisticated things with that by connecting the child's streams to `pipe()`s that the parent or some other process can read, but the simplest thing to do would be to use `dup2()` to simply direct the child's output and error streams to the socket:

```
// standard output:
if (dup2(connfd, 1) == -1) { /* handle error */ }

// standard error:
if (dup2(connfd, 2) == -1) { /* handle error */ }
```

Then the command's output, if any, will be sent directly over the wire to the client.

Answer (score 1):

this line:

```
{
    execve(args[0],args,NULL);
}
```

should be changed to:

```
{
    execve( args[0],args,NULL );
    perror( "execve failed" );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}
```

Then, the code does not continue to execute if the call to `execve()` fails AND if it fails, tells you why.

Note: both `exit()` and `EXIT_FAILURE` are from the header file: `stdlib.h`

Comment: I added those lines and now the server outputs execve failed: No such file or directory when I type a command that doesn't exist, but it keeps sending "OK" to the client. wait(&status) and waitpid(-1,&status,0) return -1 always no matter if the command ran successfully or didn't at all. Why is this happening? Shouldn't they return -1 only on failure because that's when the subprocess actually sends an exit status?

Comment: @JohnnyBeltran: If the command is `ls`, you'll only execute it correctly if the process is in the `/bin` directory (assuming that `ls` is found as `/bin/ls`).  If you write `/bin/ls` as the command, then you will be able to run it elsewhere.  There's an `execvp()` function that searches the directories listed in `$PATH` (the environment variable); when you don't use that (or `execvpe()` if that's available), then there is no path-based search for the executable.